# Can django-pagination do multiple paginations per page?

Tags: python, django, django-pagination

If it can't then are there any other alternatives (either Django's native pagination or an alternate package) that allows multiple paginations per page?

I would like to display a list of about 5 objects with each object having its own pagination context.

For convenience, here is the [documentation for django-pagination](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pagination).

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. Did you find anything?

Answer (score 9):

I know this post is old, but it is still relevant. The following will work for Django 1.9.

This is how to do it,

views.py

```
def myview():
    Model_one = Model.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(Model_one, 6)
    page = request.GET.get('page1')
    try:
        Model_one = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        Model_one = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        Model_one = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    Model_two = Model_other.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(Model_two, 6)
    page = request.GET.get('page2')
    try:
        Model_two = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        Model_two = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        Model_two = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {'Model_one': Model_one, 'Model_two': Model_two}
    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

The important thing above is the 'page1' and 'page2'.

In the template,

```
    {% if model_one %}
      <div class="col-md-12 well">
        {% for item in model_one %}
        ..... iterates through model_one.....
        {% endfor %}
        <span class="step-links pagination">
            {% if model_one.has_previous %}
                <a href="?page1={{ model_one.previous_page_number }}"> previous </a>
            {% endif %}
            <span class="current">
                Page {{ model_one.number }} of {{ model_one.paginator.num_pages }}
            </span>
            {% if model_one.has_next %}
                <a href="?page1={{ model_one.next_page_number }}"> next </a>
            {% endif %}
        </span>
      </div>
      {% endif %}
      {% if model_two %}
      <div class="col-md-12 well">
        {% for item in model_two %}
        ..... iterates through model_two.....
        {% endfor %}
        <span class="step-links pagination">
            {% if model_two.has_previous %}
                <a href="?page2={{ model_two.previous_page_number }}"> previous </a>
            {% endif %}
            <span class="current">
                Page {{ model_two.number }} of {{ model_two.paginator.num_pages }}
            </span>
            {% if model_two.has_next %}
                <a href="?page2={{ model_two.next_page_number }}"> next </a>
            {% endif %}
        </span>
      </div>
      {% endif %}
```

Again using 'page1' and 'page2' to distinguish the pagination for each model.

Answer (score 7):

Sure, it is possible. I can't speak for the django-pagination package, but it definitely is possible using the default Django's `Paginator` class. You can create as many of them as you want inside your view. Just choose different GET parameters to specify the page for each of them and you're good to go.